# fix Mangled Export names in C++

Tags: c++, windows, dll, dllexport, name-mangling

I am new to C++ and wanted to write a DLL with some exports, but I'm getting mangled names when compiled. I know by now that in order to fix this I should add `extern "C"`  in front of the declaration, but this still doesn't work.

### My Code

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

#ifdef FXSST_EXPORTS
#define FXSST_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define FXSST_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

extern "C" FXSST_API void Hello(void);
FXSST_API void Hello(void)
{
    cout << "Hello World" << endl;
}
```

For personal reasons (and making it easier for myself), I'd like to keep everything in one `.cpp` file if possible.

Thanks ;)

Comment: Define the phrase _doesn't work_.

Comment: How did you verify that the symbol is mangled?

Comment: Did you try putting `extern "C"` in front of the function definition?

Comment: The best way to control the names of the exports is to use a .def file.

Comment: @user2079303 I did `dumpbin /exports` on the file and got `?HelloWorld@@YAXXZ + ....` clear enough ?
@Galik yes as you can see in my code I did use `extern "C" ` in the function definistion.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius the `extern "C"` doesn't unmangle these export names .

Comment: @TomKustermans No, your function _declaration_ has `extern "C"`, your function _definition_ - doesn't. While, in fact, both must have `extern "C"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest thing would be to setup your DLL project to create an import library (.lib) with a header (.h) file that declares your class. Then you add the .lib to your link libraries in the project that uses the DLL, and #include your header where you need to use the class.

[MSDN on building dlls](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1ez7dh12.aspx)

Comment: I would like to know if it's possible to keep it all in one same file for the following reason: I want to compile the dll using Powershell's Add-Type command. Do you think this is possible?

Comment: No, to do what you want, it is not practically possible. What you want to do is making it far harder for yourself. It would be far simpler for you to follow the basic, standard practices.